# Singular values as continuous functions of a linear operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, singular-values

If $V$ is a complex inner product space, regard $\textrm{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(V)$ as a Banach space with the operator norm. For $T \in \textrm{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(V)$ as I understand, the singularvalues $\sigma_1(T),\cdots,\sigma_n(T)$ are continuous functions of $T$ (as their are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $TT^*$). On the other hand the set of diagonalizable operators in $\textrm{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(V)$ is dense in $\textrm{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(V)$, and for diagonalizable operators the singular values are the absolute of eigenvalues.

Now for any $T \in \textrm{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(V)$, if we consider a sequence of diagonalizable transformations $\{T_k\} \rightarrow T$, by the above argument $\sigma_i(T_k) \rightarrow \sigma_i(T), i=1,\cdots,n$. Thus it follows that the singular values of $T$ should also be the absolute of its eigenvaules, which is obviously false. Something is wrong here, but I can't figure out what is incorrect in this argument. Can anyone help me know what I am misunderstanding here? Thank you.

Comment: Singular values of diagonalazible operators are not equal to absolute values of its eigenvalues. This holds for normal operators (the basis of eigenvectors has to be an orthonormal basis for the equality $\sigma_i = |\lambda_i|$). Normal operators are not dense (density was important in your argument).

Answer (score 1):

As Matsmir commented, normality of the operator is necessary for $\sigma_i = |\lambda_i|$ to hold. The intuitive reasoning behind this is that the eigenvalues of a matrix contain no information about the extent to which a matrix has linearly dependent columns other than the fact that $\lambda = 0 \implies $ $T$ is singular. Singular values *do* quantify this information, so intuitively, the two can only be equivalent if the eigenvectors are "as linearly independent as possible", i.e. orthogonal. Obviously this is not very precise but it gives you the idea.

To give a concrete example, consider the matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 &1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$ This has eigenvalues $1$ and $0$, but has singular values $\sqrt{2}$ and $0$. Here this discrepency is because the eigenvalue is simply telling you how much $A$ scales the eigenvector $(1,0)^T$, whereas the singular value is giving a measure of how much of the "mass" of the matrix is concentrated in the corresponding rank 1 operator that projects onto $(0,1)^T$ via the singular vectors, i.e. $u_1v_1^T$. Here "mass" can be more accurately characterized by the Frobenius or induced 2-norm.

Comment: That was very insightful! Now I get it, thanks very much. Is there any relationship or a way of bounding the singular values by the eigenvalues, for a diagonalizable operator, that you are aware of?

Comment: The bound $\max|\lambda_i|\leq\sigma_{max}$ isn't too hard to show, as well as $\min|\lambda_i|\geq\sigma_{min}$. For more general bounds, they probably must include that dimensionality of the operator, as one can repeat my example with $n$ columns and the eigenvalues will remain $0$ and $1$ but the largest singular value will be $\sqrt{n}$, so these won't apply to infinite-dimensional operators